# Merge sort for an array of strings in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, sorting, merge

I have a vector of strings named "values". I want to merge sort them but I kept getting bus error or segmentation error. I know the errors are from the merge_sort function but I don't know how to fix it. Any ideas?

```
    int main()
    {
            int p=1,q=values.size()/2,r=values.size();
            merge_sort(values,p,r);

            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++)
            {
                cout << values[i] << endl;
            }

        }
}

        void merge_sort(vector<string> a,int p,int r)
        {
            int q;
            if(p<r)
            {
                q=r/2;
                merge_sort(a,p,q);
                merge_sort(a,q+1,r);
                merge(a,p,q,r);
            }
        }

        void merge(vector<string> a,int p,int q,int r)
        {
            int n1=q-p+1;
            int n2=r-q;
            string L[n1+1];
            string R[n2+1];
            for(int i=0;i<n1;i++)
            {
                L[i]=a[p+i-1];
            }
            for(int j=0;j<n2;j++)
            {
                R[j]=a[q+j];
            }
            L[n1]="ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ";
            R[n2]="ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ";

            int i=0, j=0;
            for(int k=0;k<r;k++)
            {
                if(L[i]<=R[j])
                {
                    a[k]=L[i];
                    i++;
                }
                else
                {
                    a[k]=R[j];
                    j++;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Beyond the problems with indexing and non-standard VLAs, you know your params are by-value, right? Ultimately nothing will change on the caller side.

Comment: So pass the vector by reference? I can't even get it worked now.

Comment: Well it stands no chance of working without the input vector passed by reference, even if/when you get the math right.

Comment: What WhozCraig is saying is, since you passed your vector by value a copy of it is made for functions merge() and mergeSort(). They only modify the copies. The original remains unchanged. You should be passing by reference.

Comment: OK, pass it like "vector<string> &a", right? My problem is the sort_merge function is not right.

Comment: That would probably be a good guess. I don't think your `merge` looks correct, not just `merge_sort`, but this is the second time I've seen that implementation, unneeded sentinels and all,  and time hasn't done it any favors. [An iterator solution](http://ideone.com/w0bkWX) is generally easier in C++ anyway..